# regular expression to retain only img src text

Tags: c#, regex

i have a string as given:

`< img src='^f('hImagepath')[1].label()^MegaMillions_NoBkgd.png'/>`

i want a regular expression which would return me "MegaMillions_NoBkgd.png" this part of the above string
the result after using the regular expression should be "MegaMillions_NoBkgd.png" stored in a string variable.

thanks in advance

Comment: Regex.Match(html, "<img.*src=[\"'](.+?)[\"'].*> .*", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase).Groups[1].Value;

Comment: For this to even be answerable, you need to add some more info about what can vary in your string. I assume `< img src='^f('hImagepath')[1].label()^` is not constant? So what rules apply?

Comment: ok to make it simpler atleast i need the whole src value:'^f('hImagepath')[1].label()^MegaMillions_NoBkgd.png'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Then I believe this should give you what you need, more or less:

```
 var x =  "< img src='^f('hImagepath')[1].label()^MegaMillions_NoBkgd.png'/>";

 // Result will be: 
 // ^f('hImagepath')[1].label()^MegaMillions_NoBkgd.png'
 var result = Regex.Match(x, @"\^f\((.)*'").Value;
```

Of course the simpler and more readable solution would be to do something like this, and avoid using a regex completely:

```
var x =  "<img src='^f('hImagepath')[1].label()^MegaMillions_NoBkgd.png'/>";
var urlStart = x.IndexOf("'") + 1;
var urlStop = x.LastIndexOf("'");
var result = x.Substring(urlStart, (urlStop - urlStart));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string matchString = Regex.Match(original_text, @"(<img([^>]+)>)").Value;
```

Comment: this returns the complete img tag

Answer (score 0):

This will give you the expected result:

```
string s = "< img src='^f('hImagepath')[1].label()^MegaMillions_NoBkgd.png'/>";
int start = s.LastIndexOf('^');
int stop = s.LastIndexOf('\'');

string result = s.Substring(start+1, stop-start-1);
```